# How to replace string in Excel and check whole cell string?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, replace

I want to use Python to replace strings in my CSV or Excel file. My code runs but I have the problem that if I have something like:

Replace: "rechts" with "right" and "rechts schiebend" with "right pushing"

That the replace doesn't look up for the whole cell value and translates every "rechts" to "right" then looks for "rechts schiebend" and can't find it anymore.

Is there a way to, like in Excel, look up for the whole cell string?

Here is the code I used so far:

```
import csv

reps = {
    'rechts' : 'right',
    'rechts schiebend' : 'right pushing'}

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in reps.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

with open('Test.csv','r') as f:
    text=f.read()
    text=replace_all(text,reps)

with open('Test_en.csv','w') as w:
    w.write(text)
```

Comment: What about looking and replacing `rechts` and `schiebend` separately?

Comment: Would work in this small example, but not with the whole CSV because this would cause some weird translations.

Comment: Can you include a few other example cases in your question?

Comment: @mk1337: Replace `'rechts schiebend' : 'right pushing'}` with `'schiebend' : 'pushing'}` means avoid **sentences** and **double** words. If you need to have **sentences** run all **sentences** before **single word**.

Comment: I did it like you suggestes at first and now using pandas. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the csv to `pandas.DataFrame` and use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to convert all the values.

```py
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")

reps = {
    'rechts': 'right',
    'rechts schiebend': 'right pushing'
}
translator = lambda x: reps[x] if x in reps else x
modified_test = test.applymap(translator)
modified_test.to_csv('Test_en.csv', index=None) # save result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
import re
csv = 'rechts,rechts schiebend,schiebend,schiebend rechts'

reps = {
    'rechts' : 'right',
    'rechts schiebend' : 'right pushing'
}

cells = csv.split(',')

for idx, cell in enumerate(cells):
    if cell in reps:
        cells[idx] = re.sub(re.compile('^' + cell + '$'), reps[cell], cell)

csv = ','.join(cells)

print(csv)
```

It should update the csv to

```
right,right pushing,schiebend,schiebend rechts
```